# How to force an asp.net control to reload the postback data?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, postback

What is the best practice to force the postback Data and ViewState data to be re-loaded on the code behind?

The reason I ask this is, i have one gridview which is generated dynamically and I when it is structure is generated the postback data is already loaded and I want to forse asp.net to reload the postback data once I have my gridView structure is generated.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can simple disable ViewState? Disabling this, in all postback data is reloaded

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possibe, but it's not necessary anyway. You just need to build your gridView structure at an earlier page event (eg `OnInit`).

Comment: What if the gridview structure is based on some controls' values that resides in UI? This means I have to regenerate my control after.